Applying an affine transformation using OpenCV, skimage, and scipy returns different results
I'd like to apply a homography matrix to transform a very large (50kx50k pixels). On the small scale, both cv2 and skimage apply a matrix in a predictable way. However, SciPy (which has large image support in Dask Image) doesn't transform the image in a predictable way and I can't work out why. If I could get SciPy to work, I can easily affine transform my large image with Dask.
Strangely, SciPy seems to correctly rotate the image but not scale. If the affine matrix is inverted, the scaling is correct but the rotation is inverted. Here's example code to replicate:
import scipy
import cv2
import skimage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the homography matrix
translation = np.array([[1, 0, 40],  # Translate by (0.2, 0.1)
                        [0, 1, -48],
                        [0, 0, 1]])

# Rotate by 45 degrees
rotation_angle = np.deg2rad(45)  
rotation = np.array([[np.cos(rotation_angle), -np.sin(rotation_angle), 0],
                     [np.sin(rotation_angle), np.cos(rotation_angle), 1],
                     [0, 0, 1]])

# Scale by 2x
scaling = np.array([[2, 0, 0],  
                    [0, 2, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1]])

# Combine transformations
affine_matrix = translation @ rotation @ scaling

# Apply transformations
image = skimage.data.astronaut()
skimage_result = skimage.transform.warp(
        image,
        np.linalg.inv(affine_matrix),
    )
cv2_result = cv2.warpAffine(image, 
                        affine_matrix[:2],
                        dsize=(image.shape[1], image.shape[0])
                        )
scipy_result = []
scipy_result_inverted = []
for ch in range(image.shape[2]):
     # Apply to each RGB channel independently
    loop_result = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(
            image[..., ch],
            affine_matrix,
            order=0,
        )
    loop_result_inverted = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(
            image[..., ch],
            np.linalg.inv(affine_matrix),
            order=0,
        )
    scipy_result.append(loop_result)
    scipy_result_inverted.append(loop_result_inverted)

scipy_result = np.stack(scipy_result).transpose(1, 2, 0)
scipy_result_inverted = np.stack(scipy_result_inverted).transpose(1, 2, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20, 10))
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[1].imshow(skimage_result)
ax[2].imshow(cv2_result)
ax[3].imshow(scipy_result)
ax[4].imshow(scipy_result_inverted)

ax[1].set_title("skimage.transform.warp")
ax[2].set_title("cv2.warpAffine")
ax[3].set_title("scipy.ndimage.affine_transform")
ax[4].set_title("scipy.ndimage.affine_transform\nInverted matrix")

Example transformations plot

Note that in images the y axis is inverted, so rotation angles are inverted as well.

Might it be simply a definition difference in which way is positive rotation?

If their two rotate functions are any indication, OpenCV rotates clockwise by default (https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4ad01c0978b0ce64baa246811deeac24) and Skimage rotates counterclockwise by default (https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rotate)

they all apply the transformation matrix correctly, or should. at most, some of them need an inverted matrix, or not. opencv's warpaffine/warpperspective take the forward transform. they invert it internally for the "pull" sampling, which itself inverts, so all is good.

generating a rotation matrix from just an angle value may have some funny conventions. opencv's getRotationMatrix2D rotates from +X to -Y, i.e. "counterclockwise" in a "X right Y down" coordinate frame, which looks like positive rotation in a "X right Y up" frame. someone 20+ years ago wrote that function and decided this behavior on a whim. now it's an API and nobody will ever be able to correct that insanity.

So, I worked out the solution to my problem: you have to inverse the homography matrix since SciPy uses a pull/backward transform, which contrasts cv2 and skimage which use a push transform (I think).
Additionally, you need to switch the XY axes using transpose. You then undo this with another transpose after transformation.
So, with these two changes in mind, using scipy.ndimage.affine_transform would be as follows:
transformed_image = scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(
        image.T,
        np.linalg.inv(affine_matrix)[:2],
    ).T


well opencv also pulls (that's the only way to do it), but it takes the forward transform and inverts it for the pull step. perhaps scipy is more explicit about this reality of the math.
